# C++ 11 Template Variable Design

Tags: c++, c++11

I have a lot of subclasses of an abstract class Letter, like A, B, C, D, etc.  Letter has an integer ID variable, and every subclass of Letter gets assigned a unique id.

I then have another class, call it Alphabet.  Alphabet has an

```
list<shared_ptr<Letter>>
```

member.  Here is the problem... I would like to elegantly add B's and C's or other subclasses of Letter to particular instances of Alphabets.  I think the most convenient way to do this would be to use the integer id of subclass somehow.  In other words, I want to be able to have something like Alphabet.addLetter(int id), so if I did alphabet1.add(14), it would somehow add a shared_ptr for class H to the list.

Is there an elegant way to do this, avoiding some huge if statement where that I need to constantly update every time I add or remove one of the B, C, D, E, etc. classes?  I'm hoping there's some kind of template-solution, but I'm not very familiar with advanced c++ notions like factories and templates.  The naive thing I wanted was some kind of vector/map that converted my ids into class names, so that I could do something like

```
list.push_back(shared_ptr<classVector(i)>(new classVector(i))
```

or something like that, though I have no idea if that's possible.

Thanks!

p.s. I just chose the Alphabet example because I didn't want to give unnecessary detail.  Obviously I'm not trying to design alphabets in such a silly way, lol.

edit: I'm struggling to make this make sense.  My goal is to be able to create new subclasses of Letter very quickly with minimal effort.  I would like to avoid having to type out code that looks like...

```
list.push_back(shared_ptr<X>(...));
```

every time I make a new letter.  Does this make sense at all?

Comment: I'm really struggling to follow this.

Comment: Seriously? "I have a lot of subclasses of an abstract class A, like B, C, D, etc. A has an integer ID variable, and every subclass of A gets assigned a unique id." How about a class `letter` with an int constructor that assigns the "unique id"?

Comment: Instead of using arbitrary integer IDs, take advantage of polymorphism and dynamic binding.

Comment: I was wondering about this as well.  Put another way, if you have many subclasses of an abstract class and an instance is in a generic list (for example) and you need to determine the precise subclass of the generic instance, how do you do it?  Or is this a wrong-minded question?

Comment: Are you sure you need id at all? I think shared_ptr<B> will be automatically converted to shared_ptr<A> if b is derived from a and b is passed into function that accepts a.

Comment: @Jim You'd `dynamic_cast`, or in case of `shared_ptr`, you'd `dynamic_pointer_cast`. But I can't figure out if that's what the OP is asking.

Comment: You can create a factory, then use the factory to create your objects (i.e. `create(id)` returns `class_id`. In this way, you have to implement a switch only in the factory. I am not sure that is what you want, but I also agree with @Zeks that `shared_ptr<Derived>` should convert to `shared_ptr<Base>` for a `Derived` class. And in any case, your container has to be of a `Base` type, and all elements will be accessible through the `Base` interface. Here is a nice example (although a bit more sophisticated) http://blog.fourthwoods.com/2011/06/04/factory-design-pattern-in-c/

Comment: Oh. when I saw the title I was expecting C++14's template variables implementation in C++11 (ie **an interesting question**), not **THIS**

Comment: @Manu343726 Sorry to disappoint you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is relatively easy if I understood you correctly, using what's called a factory-pattern.

## If you can list all of the derived types:

Letter header:

```
struct Letter {
    enum LetterEnum {LetterA, LetterB, LetterC, LetterCount};
    
    virtual ~Letter() {} //base types should always have virtual destructor
    virtual void foo() = 0;
  
    static std::unique_ptr<Letter> construct(LetterEnum c);
};
```

Implementation headers:

```
struct A : Letter {
  void foo() override;
};

struct B : Letter {
  void foo() override;
};

struct C : Letter {
  void foo() override;
};
```

Letter body:

```
std::unique_ptr<Letter> Letter::construct(Letter::LetterEnum c) 
{
    switch(c) {
    case Letter::LetterA : return make_unique<A>();
    case Letter::LetterB : return make_unique<B>();
    case Letter::LetterC : return make_unique<C>();
    default: throw ...;
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
int main() {
    char c;
    std::cin >> c;
    //get a letter of the derived type associated with the letter entered
    std::unique_ptr<Letter> ptr = Letter::construct(c);    
}
```

## If you can't list all of the derived types:

Allow the derived types to register themselves with the `Letter` class, and then `Letter` can use that to create each of the derived types.  This way, adding and deleting the derived types involves *no* changes to any other files.  Easy!

```
struct Letter {
    virtual ~Letter() {} //destructor is always virtual when inheretence is involved
    ....
    //this is a "shared" function in the Letter class itself
    //it takes a letter, and returns a dynamically allocated instance
    //of the derived type corresponding with that letter
    static std::unique_ptr<Letter> construct(char c);
    //this typedef represents the actual function that returns 
    //each dynamically allocated derived type
    typedef std::function<std::unique_ptr<Letter>()> letter_ctor;
    //this is a "shared" function in the Letter class itself
    //it takes a letter, and a function that creates derived types, 
    //and saves them inside the container ctors
    static bool register(char c, letter_ctor func);
private:
    //this is a "shared" member in the Letter class.  
    //There is only one shared by all of the Letters.  Like a global.
    //When you give it a letter, it gives you a function.
    //and is VERY fast for large numbers of entries
    static std::unordered_set<char,letter_ctor> ctors;
};
```

and in your implementation file:

```
//here's the function that derived types register themselves with
//pretty straightforward, just inserts the pair into the unordered_map
bool Letter::register(char c, Letter::letter_ctor func)
{return Letter::ctors.insert(std::make_pair(c,std::move(func))).second;}

//and here's the function that creates the derived types
//it checks if the letter is in the unordered_map
//if the letter isn't there, it throws an exception
//otherwise, it calls the function associated with that letter
//which creates the derived type on the heap, and returns a pointer to it
std::unique_ptr<Letter> Letter::construct(char c) 
{
     auto it = Letter::ctors.find(c);
     if (it == Letter::ctors.end())
         throw ...;
     return it->second(); //construct that letter
}
```

and then your derived types do this:

```
//you know this part
struct LetterA : public Letter 
{
   ....
};
//derived types have to register themselves:
//this is a global, so when the program loads, it automatically calls this
//even before main runs*
//it registers the letter 'A' and a function that creates a LetterA class on the heap
static bool registerA = Letter::register('A', [](){return make_unique<LetterA>();});
```

and then you can easily create arbirary derived types!

```
int main() {
    char c;
    std::cin >> c;
    //get a letter of the derived type associated with the letter entered
    std::unique_ptr<Letter> ptr = Letter::construct(c);
}
```

*It doesn't *always* get called before main.  If you have problems, put an `bool init_A();` in the A header, and `bool init_A(){return true;}` in the A implementation file, and in your main file have `static bool AInit=init_A();` which should force it.  This is almost never needed in practice though.

---

As a side note, these depend on having a `make_unique`, which *should* have been in C++11, but was left out due to oversight.  It will be in C++14.  In the meantime, use this:

```
template<class T, class...Us>
std::unique_ptr<T> make_unique(Us&&...us) 
{return std::unique_ptr<T>(new T(std::forward<Us>(us)...));}
```

Comment: It's going to take me a while to understand this because it uses a lot of keywords that I don't really understand yet, but I think this is the answer to my question.

Comment: @user3281410: I added many comments to explain the bits and pieces

Comment: Being stupid here, when you say you can easily create derived types, you mean at compile time right? Because it's just a new entry.  Not at run time, right?  I've heard of run time class creation, but I think that's more involved.

Comment: @Jim: Yeah, What I mean is that you create the new class, and add the `register` line, and you're good to go.  You don't have to find code in some other random files and edit them to know about your newly created class.  In Jeff's answer you have to edit `LetterCode` in some header file, and Klaus's doesn't seem able to create based on a variable identifier at all.

Comment: Thank you so much Mooing Duck.  This is exactly what I wanted.  I wanted 1 simple line of code that I could put somewhere, exactly what your Letter::register(..) lines do.  This will definitely be the most unusual looking code I've ever written when I'm done, lol.

Comment: But you use a string ('A', 'B', etc.) to designate the new class right?  Because anything else (like an enumeration) would involve change some other file. Maybe you could have an enumeration in the factory area....

Comment: @Jim: Yes, this approach works with strings and such.  Using an enum would kind of defeat the point of this approach.  If you're going to have an enum, there's far better approaches to use than this one.  But the joy of this approach is that it doesn't require changing another file(for most compilers).  If he needs an enum, then something closer to the other two answers would be best I think.  The vector using enums as indexes still lets you pick types based on runtime values.

Comment: @Jim For what I'm doing, I'm going to just declare integer constants for each of the particular letters instead of characters.  Each of my alphabet objects can only have 1 letter of a particular type, so I can use the integers to search and pull the pointers out of the list and then cast the pointer to the particular class I wanted using its integer id.  Something like static_cast<X>(alphabet1.getLetter(CLASS_X_ID)).

Comment: @MooingDuck I don't see how the `register()` approach is any better a drop-in than the trait type system. It actually defers more setup to dynamic (albeit start-up) run-time, including potential failures and race conditions. I agree that using `std::unique_ptr<T>` is the way to go over `std::shared_ptr<T>`, but I do disagree that `std::unordered_map` is the way to go if user3281410 constrols the denstity of the codings him/herself.

Comment: OK, didn't mean to be a butt-in-ski, but this has been very helpful in understanding these concepts.  Thank you!

Comment: @MooingDuck In what case would i need an enum?  I'm fine with an exception getting thrown if you try to construct a letter when its code doesn't exist, which is what your code does, I think.

Comment: @user3281410, I brought up the enum issue because some people wouldn't want to designate/identify the different classes in that manner.  They'd want something more formal.  But different people need different things and have different demands.

Comment: @Jeff: the difference is that all of type `A` can be in a single cpp file with no references outside of the file and it still works.  For the type trait, you'd have to go find the right header(s) to add the type trait in.  If the set of derived types is definitely known ahead of time though, you're right that an enum would be better.  I'd forgotten that this concept was designed for base types where the derived types are an open set, which seems to not be the poster's use-case.

Comment: Now I don't know what to do.  I understand what MooingDuck's code does, and it does what I want.  But I could easily make an enum instead of just using arbitrary integers, since I am going to be making all of these subclasses myself.  Does that mean I should accept Jeff's answer?  And also, Jeff is now saying that unique_ptr's are better, and I have no idea why lol.  In any case, thank you everyone that responded because I am learning a lot.

Comment: @MooingDuck at this point it seems user3281410 wants construction keyed off dynamic values, which I didn't think was what he wanted at first, so your solution may be the necessary one at this point.

Comment: @user3281410 My comment around `unique_ptr` being better than `shard_ptr` is based off the assumption that the `Alphabet` instances will wholly own the `Letter` instances and not share them around, in which case the added overhead of  `shared_ptr` buys you nothing.

Comment: @Jeff That makes sense.  Am I correct in accepting this answer then, since it's the only way that I can have dynamic values instead of literal ones?

Comment: @user3281410: I have expanded my answer to show both of the major ways of implementing the factory pattern, as I interpreted your question slightly differently than Jeff did.  As for which you should accept, it depends on who answered your question better.  It could be that I misinterpreted.

Comment: I think my situation is best described by the top of MooingCow's post.

Comment: @user3281410 Most likely, unless the only time you use the dynamic value initialization is in a contiguous 0...n loop, in which case a recursive template function would probably be preferable.

Answer (score 8):

This is pretty hard to follow, but I think what you want is something along the lines of the following:

```
// where make_unique<> is from C++14 in std:: or like:
template <typename T, typename ... TArgs>
std::unique_ptr<T> make_unique(TArgs &&... args) {
  return std::unique_ptr<T>(new T(std::forward<TArgs>(args)...));
}

struct Letter {
  virtual ~Letter() { }
  virtual void foo() = 0;
};
template <unsigned int N> struct LetterCode; // Note: no default implementation!

struct Alphabet {
  // Indexed access, if you'll have 1 of each type max:
  std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Letter>> v;

  // If you don't need parameters, as mentioned in comments below ...
  template <unsigned int N>
  void addLetterN() {
    if (N > v.size() + 1) { v.resize(N + 1); }
    v[N] = make_unique<LetterCode<N>::type>(); // see below ...
  }

  // If your coding is complete from 0...N, this does the whole shebang.
  template <unsigned int N>
  void addLettersN() {
    addLetters<N - 1>();
    addLetterN<N>();
  }
  template <>
  addLettersN<0>() {
    addLetterN<0>();
  }
};
```

If you need numeric codes for something like deserialization and never need constructor arguments, you can use a type trait template like follows to statically 'register' the types:

```
struct B : Letter {
  B(int n, bool b, char const *name);
  void foo() override;
};
template <> struct LetterCode<2> { using type = B; };

struct C : Letter {
  C(double d);
  void foo() override;
};
template <> struct LetterCode<3> { using type = C; };

void bar() {
  Alphabet a;
  a.addLetterN<2>();
  a.addLetterN<3>();

  // --OR--
  a.addLettersN<3>(); // will do 0...3 in one fell swoop.

  for (auto &i : a.v) {
    if (!i) { continue; } // v is sparse, unlike l
    i->foo();
}
```

If you need generalized constructor argument passing, you can use perfect forwarding, which is designed for cases like this and obviates the need for enum IDs, etc., from older styles of factories:

```
struct Alphabet {
  std::list<std::unique_ptr<Letter>> l;

  // variadic factory that chucks new (shared_ptr) objects in the list.
  template <typename T, typename ... TArgs>
  void addLetter(TArgs && ... args) {
    l.push_back(make_unique<T>(std::forward<TArgs>(args)...));
  }
};

void baz() {
  Alphabet a;
  a.addLetter<B>(1, false, "pony");
  a.addLetter<C>(2.718281828);

  for (auto &i : a.l) {
    i->foo(); // can call virtual funcs here all you want ...
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you Jeff.  In my particular context all of the subclasses are just there to implement an abstract function that computes a float.  I don't have to pass anything to them in their constructor.  My goal is to be able to create a new subclass without having to hunt down a bunch of places in my code where I need to make changes.  In your example, I would ideally not want to type the "B" in foo(). I want to just type addLetter(1). Does that make any sense at all?

Comment: Why "1"? Are you keying off hardcoded literal integers, or getting a stream of dynamic integer values from somewhere else that you need to turn into new object instances?

Comment: They would be hardcoded literals.  Every alphabet would have at most one letter of a given class (should have said that earlier).  I would be able to use the integer as the "name" for the letter, since any alphabet would have only 1 letter with a particular id.  I guess I want all of the letters to be pushed into the list in the same way, without having to write any extra code programmed new subclasses or removed subclass types from my code.  But when they are in the list, they will implement abstract functions differently giving me different output based on what letter they are.

Comment: It sounds like you might want to use a directly indexed structure for your `shared_ptr`s rather than a `std::list<>` then?

Comment: Each alphabet needs to have its own copy of each letter since the letters may have local variables that are particular to the alphabet they are in.  Maybe the letter A needs to do things differently depending on some of its local variables.  As an aside, I'm started to really regret this stupid alphabet analogy, lol.

Comment: In the future, just say `Base` and `Derived` or `B` and `D`, since that's more idiomatic. How close is my solution to your needs at this point?

Comment: I'm still reading through all of this.  I didn't notice that you edited it significantly since I read it over at first.  It seems like your code also does what Mooing Duck's does above.  I can't tell which approach is better though.

Comment: If you are assigning the int codes yourself and pretty densely, I think that `vector` is definitely better than `unordered_map`, but MooingDuck's use of `unique_ptr` is better than the `shared_ptr` use that I kept. I also think that my notation is equally if not more compact while doing more of the work at compile-time.

Comment: What did people do before C++ 11?  It seems most of these approaches are pretty leading edge, given there aren't many full C++ 11 compilers out there yet.

Comment: @Jim things were much nastier looking. To be fair though, gcc (and tr1, and boost before that) had a lot of the features for years earlier if you could forego a bit of inter-platform compatibility.

Comment: @Jim: There are a great many compilers out there that handle the day-to-day C++11 stuff.

Comment: @Jeff I'm having a bit of a harder time deciphering this.  In the bar function would i be able to call addLetter and put a variable integer inside the template area thing instead of actually typing 1 or 2 like you do?  That's my chief goal.  To be clear, can I write a.addLetter<myInteger> ?

Comment: @MooingDuck true, Clang, g++, VC++, icc, etc. all do now. Support has gotten pretty substantial.

Comment: @user3281410 definitely not, unfortunately. You said in the third comment above that you were using hardcoded literals, which this optimizes for.

Comment: @Jeff Ok well I feel bad now because I'm clearly making no sense.  I should have said that my integers were hardcoded, but they aren't literals, I missed that.  For example, I was going to make the integers static constants inside each of the letter subclasses.

Answer (score 1):

My understanding is that you want to create a instance of one of the classes, dependend on an id which relates to the class from which an instance should be created.

If so, please have a look for factory pattern. There are a lot of factory implementations, also based on template recursive expansion of a typelist.

Pseudo Code:

```
Factory<A,B,C,D> fac; // the list must be changed, if some more classes comes and goes
id_type id;

list<base> l;

l.push_back=fac.Create(id);
```

It is also quite simple to implement such a class yourself.

Comment: For others that can't decipher my apparently opaque question, yes this is what I want to do.  I am going to go read about factory patterns, since I don't immediately see how your code does anything.  Maybe that's the right thing to google to figure it out though, thanks!

Comment: I am not sure you need an ID instead of just template member function in this factory

Comment: As I understand, it is part of the question that OP has an idea to create the related class. The factory should replace a switch/case/if tree. I understand that OP wants to 'Create a new instance of class which has the given ID'. So ID is needed :-)

Answer (score 0):

The goal is simple: create the function factories that returns an array of Alphabet makers.

The index of the letter and the index into the array will be the same.

Ideally, we want to auto-generate said index without having to manually set it.

```
#include <memory>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

template<class T>using Type=T;

template<class...Ts>struct types:std::integral_constant<unsigned,sizeof...(Ts)>
{typedef types type;};
template<class T,class types>struct index_of;
template<class T,class T0, class...Ts>struct index_of<T,types<T0,Ts...>>:
  std::integral_constant<unsigned,index_of<T,types<Ts...>>::value+1>
{};
template<class T,class...Ts>struct index_of<T,types<T,Ts...>>:
  std::integral_constant<unsigned,0>
{};
template<unsigned,class types>struct type_at;
template<unsigned N, class T,class...Ts>struct type_at<N,types<T,Ts...>>:
  type_at<N-1,types<Ts...>> {};
template<class T,class...Ts>struct type_at<0,types<T,Ts...>>{
  typedef T type;
};
template<unsigned N,class types>
using type_at_t=typename type_at<N,types>::type;

template<template<class>class Target,unsigned N,class types>
struct nth_apply;
template<template<class>class Target,unsigned N,class...Ts>
struct nth_apply<Target,N,types<Ts...>>{
  typedef Target<type_at_t<N,types<Ts...>>> type;
};
template<template<class>class Target,unsigned N,class types>
using nth_apply_t=typename nth_apply<Target,N,types>::type;
```

This is the type that produces the function pointers for us:

```
template<class T>struct shared_maker{
  template<class...Args>
  std::shared_ptr<T> operator()(Args&&...args)const{
    return std::make_shared<T>(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
  }
  template<class R, class... Args>
  operator Type<R(Args...)>*() const{
    return [](Args... args)->R{
      return shared_maker{}(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
    };
  }
};
```

Here is what we do for the actual letter types.  We forward declare them:

```
struct A; struct B; // etc
```

Stick them into a list of types:

```
typedef types<A,B> Alphabet_Types;
```

Now, our simple test `Alphabet` type:

```
struct Alphabet {
  virtual unsigned get_index() const = 0;
};
```

And a CRTP helper that gets the index of the letter from its offset into the list of types!  The `virtual` get_indexes is just for debugging:

```
template<class D>
struct Letter:Alphabet{
  static const unsigned index = index_of<D, Alphabet_Types>::value;
  virtual unsigned get_index() const override { return index; }
};
```

Now the signature of our array-producer:

```
typedef std::shared_ptr<Alphabet> spAlphabet;
std::array<spAlphabet(*)(), Alphabet_Types::value> factories();
```

Here is how we define our (toy) letter classes:

```
struct A:Letter<A>{};
struct B:Letter<B>{};
```

ie, use Letter<> as a CRTP base instead of Alphabet.

The only thing left is to write the function `factories`.

Index boilerplate.  C++1y has a replacement:

```
template<unsigned...>struct indexes{typedef indexes type;};
template<unsigned Max, unsigned... Is> struct make_indexes:make_indexes<Max-1,Max-1,Is...>{};
template<unsigned...Is>struct make_indexes<0,Is...>:indexes<Is...>{};
```

The actual implementation via a helper function.  We get a pack of indexes and expand it, building our `std::array` of function pointers from our `shared_maker` above instantiated with an indexed type from the `Alphabet_Types` we wrote above:

```
template<unsigned...Is>
std::array<spAlphabet(*)(), Alphabet_Types::value> factories(indexes<Is...>){
  return {nth_apply_t<shared_maker,Is,Alphabet_Types>{}...};
}
```

The actual `factories` function just forwards to the above helper:

```
std::array<spAlphabet(*)(), Alphabet_Types::value> factories(){
  return factories(make_indexes<Alphabet_Types::value>{});
}
```

And some trivial test code:

```
int main() {
  std::vector<spAlphabet> vec;
  auto builders = factories();
  for (int i = 0; i < 2; ++i) {
    vec.push_back(builders[i]());
  }
  for( auto&& ptr:vec ) {
    std::cout << ptr->get_index() << "\n";
  }
}
```